# UITableView reloadData does not seem to cause cellForRowAtIndexPath: to be called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am currently writing an app, using storyboards, that contains two `UITableView`s within the same window.

When running the application, the first `UITableView` will populate with a number of "Registration Numbers".

When the user taps on a cell, then the second `UITableView` is supposed to populate with detail about the selected cell.

When tapping a number in the first table I have a method that drives the:

```
[mySecondTableView reloadData]
```

Which it does.  I am under the impression that when invoking the `reloadData` command, it should then call both:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The first fires, but the second won't.
I have both the data source and delegate wired to self.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Are both methods meant to fire?

Comment: It's also not at all certain that iOS 7 is even relevant here; these methods were present in Cocoa Touch well prior to that system version.

Comment: What is numberOFRowsInSection returning? Is it 0?

Comment: rdelmar - No, there are 16 objects to show and it returns that number.

Comment: What's the second table view's `frame`, `contentSize`, and `superview`?

Comment: Can you show us more code? Is there one delegate/datasource for both tableViews. If the latter is the case that might cause your problem.

Comment: Why should it - THE CELL IT MIGHT NOT BE SHOWN ON THE SCREEN

Answer (score 34):

When things like this happen to me, it's usually because I'm calling `-reloadData` outside of the main thread.

Comment: This is something so easily overlooked especially when working with completion handlers invoked from background threads. Excellent tip.

Comment: Banged my head on this for hours. Finally got it to work after reading this. Thanks. Be careful of completion blocks like Bart says. Make sure you call [tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]

Answer (score 19):

After reloadData, try this:

```
NSIndexSet * sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
[self.tableView reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

I found if the data change is subtle, the table view seems to optimize away the need to refresh.

Comment: For some reason, this actually fixed it for me. That's wrong!

Comment: @OlivaresF - Thanks, this worked for me, moves inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. but not refreshing in TableView.

Comment: indexSetwithindex methods are no longer available in swift, and i am facing this same reloaddata problem

Comment: the only thing that worked for me after days of headaches. WHY XCODE WHY

Answer (score 3):

Pointed answers doesn't solve my table view problem. It was still calling

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

however cell drawing method wasn't fired:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

My problem was that(because of my mistake of course) table view height was 0. So as table displays only cells that are visible, it never tries to display a cell. When I changed height value drawing cell method started to fire again.

Botom line **double check your table frame and ensure you have non-zero width and height values!**

Answer (score 1):

I just incurred this same issue. I used a `performSelectorOnMainThread` to call a method which then calls the `reloadData`. This was necessary since I was trying to update outside the main thread as suggested by hatfinch.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call performSelectorOnMainThread with waitUntilDone:NO, otherwise you may still have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Found another cause of cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called.

If `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 0, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` won't be called.
This happened in my case because of an NSArray being de-allocated during a view controller change and its consequent count (since it was nil) returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against a wall for days this solved my problem:

Set the All Exceptions breakpoint and see if you are getting an out of bounds exception in your datasource. Without setting the breakpoint there is no crash and the tableview will simply fail to reload.

Full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32124455/4114835)

Answer (score 0):

I was debugging a similar issue for hours before I realized my `.reloadData()` call was being executed by a callback of a previous instance of the view controller.

So my breakpoint was hitting on the `.reloadData()` call of my old instance of that view controller, but the new instance that was actually shown wasn't reloading because it wasn't the one executing the callback that called `.reloadData()`.