# tableView reloadData not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I call `[tableView reloadData]` the function `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is not fired? Why?

Here's my **TableView.m**

```
@implementation TableView
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize controller = _controller;
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        self.del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        self.managedObjectContext = self.del.managedObjectContext;

        [self performControllerFetch];
    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    ...
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ...
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    ...
}

-(void)reloadTableView
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

@end
```

**TableView.h**

```
@interface TableView : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *del;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *controller;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TableView *tableView;

-(void)reloadTableView;
-(void)performControllerFetch;
@end
```

Comment: Downvote seems a little misplaced, this is a legitimate question with what looks like some important design considerations that the asker should be aware of.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you are never setting the `delegate` and `datasource` properties on your tableview, no? You're implementing the methods in those protocols inside `tableview.m` but not setting the two properties to `self` hence calling `reloadData` having no effect.

Does this help?

**Edit:**

Looks like you have a `tableView` property set on a subclass of `UITableView` and hooked up to an interface builder file. This is an odd setup (a tableview within a tableview). Usually you would have something like a `UIViewController` subclass hooked up to an XIB and set an

`@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView * tableView`

in that subclass, or something similar. And then handle the data fetching and tableview delegate/datasource inside that viewcontroller subclass.

But here, because of the nested `UITableView`s it's not as straightforward. Is there a reason for this design? I recommend moving to something like I describe above to help bring clarity to the setup.

Also, try adding some `NSLog` statements into your `init` method to see if the tableview != nil and the delegate and datasource properties have been set. My suspicion is that the connection is not being made.

Also, unrelated to the problem at hand, you no longer have to manually `@synthesize ivar = _ivar`, it will be done for you automatically using the underscore convention.

Comment: I've set the delegate and the datasource in the Interface Builder to the class TableView.m. Does that reach?

Comment: Hmm, Can you post the .h file as well (what class does tablview.m inherit from)? And can you post the code where you declare your IBOutlets (if any)? Sometimes IB can be picky about whether you make the delegate/datasource connection with the "files owner" vs the view within the XIB file.

Comment: I've updated my code. btw: the data in the table is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same issue, that the **reload** was not working. I believe the **delegate** method I was calling it from was in a **background thread** which was causing the problem. My solution was to create a **new method** (below) and call the **reload** from there instead, while also ensuring to call it from the **main thread**:

```
- (void) tocLoad {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not able to reload table using

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Please make sure you are adding reference to following from the storyboard

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TableView *tableView;
```

How to add reference you can click on following Image Link:

[tableView reference outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MkVl.png)

Comment: Damn. That was it.  I had a tableview variable, but the Storyboard had disconnected it.  Xcode (and life) would be so much easier if there was just the slightest hint of error detection in Xcode, to point us in the right direction...  Grrrr....

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because there was a call to

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
```

without a call to

```
tableView.endUpdates()
```

In my code. Removing `tableView.beginUpdates()` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I spent days debugging this issue, and found a ton of possible fixes. I starred the one that worked for me but they're all valid.

First, of course, check that your delegate, datasource, IBOutlet, etc are all configured properly.

**Set the All Exceptions breakpoint and see if you are getting an out of bounds exception in your datasource. Without setting the breakpoint there is no crash and the tableview will simply fail to reload.

Other possible fixes: check the tableview's frame to make sure the width or height is not 0. Try executing reloadData on the main thread. Lastly, try only reloading a single section ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246170/4114835)).

Gotta love table views.

Answer (score -1):

Inspite of writing this  `[self.tableView reloadData];` try below, becuase already you have written class so no need to take the outlet again:-

```
[self reloadData]
```

Comment: Basically what is your problem i mean it is not refreshing the data??

Comment: Yes that's the problem.

Comment: Ok do one thing disconnect you outlet,delegate and datasource of tableview  and then only reconnect delegate and datasource of your table to your controller class and check

Comment: Basically that method should call when you connect delegate to the tableview